# Number theory problem involving linear congruences

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

**What three positive integers, upon being multiplied by 3, 5, and 7 respectively and the products divided by 20, have remainders in arithmetic progression with common difference 1 and quotients equal to remainders?**

My thought process is to solve the system of linear congruences

**(1)** $r \equiv3n_1 \pmod{20}$

**(2)** $r + 1 \equiv 5n_2 \pmod{20}$

**(3)** $ r + 2 \equiv 7n_3\pmod{20}$

If I could solve this for $r$, using the chinese remainder theorem, my thought process is that I could then find $n_1, n_2, n_3$ which work.

Plugging **(1)**  into **(2)** gives $3n_1\equiv 5n_2-1 \pmod{20}$. Since the inverse of $3$ mod $20$ is $7$, I could isolate $n_1\equiv 7(5n_2-1) \pmod{20}$.

Now I have that $r\equiv3(7(5n_2-1))=105n_2-21$ which I could then plug into the third equation.

I now have $105n_2-21\equiv7n_3-2 \pmod{20} \Rightarrow 105n_2\equiv 7n_3+19 \pmod{20} $. However, since 105 does not have an inverse mod 20 since $105$ and $20$ are not coprime, I am unable to proceed from here.

**Am I on the right track? What can I do from here to solve this problem?**

I also feel I am disregarding the part of the question which says "and quotients equal to remainders".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, one needs to solve the following: $$3n_1=20r+r,$$ $$5n_2=20(r+1)+(r+1),$$ and $$7n_3=20(r+2)+(r+2).$$ The first and third are obviously met. To solve for the second, just need to require that $r=5t-1,t\geq 1$. It follows that $$n_1=7(5t-1),n_2=21t,n_3=3(5t+1),t\geq 1.$$ If one further requires that $r+2<20$, then one can proceed to identify all solutions.

Comment: This is a great answer thanks! Could you elaborate on the last line? Where does the $r+2<20$ come from?

Comment: The question did not explicitly mentioned it, but the usual division algorithm requires that the remainder is greater or equal to zero, but strictly less than the divisor, which is 20.